Confusion About Integral Involving Periodic Functions
Let $f_p(t)$ be a periodic function with period $T$.
An identity that we often use is that
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dt \, f_p(t) 
\left[ g(t) - g(t - T) \right]
=
0
\, ,
$$
which can be shown by shifting the argument by $T$.
However, I am confused about the sufficient and necessary conditions for the equality above to hold.
As a counterexample, suppose that
$$
g(t) - g(t - T) = \Theta(t)
\, ,
$$
where $\Theta(t)$ is the Heaviside step function.
The form of $g(t)$ can be solved iteratively to give for example the particular solution
$$
g(t) = \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} \Theta(t - n T)
\, .
$$
But in this case, we would instead end up with
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dt \, f_p(t) 
\left[ g(t) - g(t - T) \right]
=
\int_0^{\infty} f_p(t) \, dt
\neq 
0
\, ,
$$
which is inconsistent with the identity written above.
I feel like I am missing something very elementary here, but couldn't figure it out. Does continuity of $g(t)$ play a role here? Hope someone here can lend a helping hand. Thanks a lot in advance!

Your identity only works when $f_p\cdot g$ is integrable, i.e.
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty |f_p(t)g(t)|dt < \infty.$$
With your example $g$, this is unlikely to be the case.
